# Extend Symfony2 White October Admin Bundle Form Fields?

Tags: symfony, bundle, symfony-forms

This question is quite specific.
I'm using Symfony2 [White October Admin Bundle](https://github.com/whiteoctober/WhiteOctoberAdminBundle) for generating administration for my application.
I wonder if anyone has experience with this bundle and knows how to modify specific fields added to Admin class. The bundle is not documented very well and I'd like to know, if there are methods for doing this, or does the bundle core need to be extended.

For example I've got a Speaker entity with a field storing the path to one's avatar:

```
/**
 * @var string $picturePath
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="picture_path", type="string", length=128, nullable=false)
 */
private $picturePath;
```

Then in the Admin class I'm adding the field:

```
protected function configure()
{
    ...
    ...
    ->addFields(array(
        ...
        ...
        'picturePath'=> array("label" => "Avatar"),
    ));
}
```

Is there an easy way to tell the bundle that I'd like this field to be an upload field instead of a text field, and define extra methods to call after submitting the form? (e.g. resize the image, store it, and then just store the image path in the DB)

Comment: I was able to replace the text field with an upload field like this:
`'picturePath'=> array("label" => "Avatar", "formType" => "file"),`
But still have no clue where to put the code to handle the upload? Gonna continue the guessing game, it helped with the field type :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I haven't found any solution yet, I had to rape my entities to do that. So I modified the basic setter methods to call other methods inside the entity that do the dirty job. This is not a solution, and I'll still be happy if I could find better answers here.